# How can I add an ant terrain to an arbitrary shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am attempting to create 3D hex models that can be used in the board game [Settlers of Catan](https://deems.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/catan-map-layout.jpg). Many of the tiles are based on geographical features (such as a mountain). The tiles are also regular hexagons. As such, I would like to use the ANT Landscape plugin to create the terrain shape and then apply it to a hexagon. I can use the circle tool to create a regular hexagon by setting the number of vertices to 6. When I create a hexagon in this manner, and then add an ANT landscape to it (by simply positioning it so that it's outermost points align with the Z value of the hexagon), I get the following:

[image: ANT landscape added to hexagon]

This has two major issues:

- The landscape is too small (I would like it to cover as much of the hexagon as possible, ideally with falloff based on the hexagon rather than square shape)
- It is impossible to have a recessed landscape as the hexagon's surface will cover it. Removing the hexagon leaves a square landscape which isn't what I want.

How can I solve both of these issues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start with a cylinder with 6 vertices. (a hexagon shape)

[image]

Then, add your landscape. Play with the settings until you like how it looks.

[image]

Now, add a Boolean modifier on your landscape mesh. Make the operation set to Intersect and the Object set to the 6 sided cylinder we added previously.

[image]

Apply the modifier. You may now delete the cylinder. it is no longer needed. Enter edit mode on the landscape mesh, and select the bottom faces using face selection. Using vertex selection, deselect the 6 vertices on the bottom. Then, with proportional editing enabled, scale the vertices that are still selected along the Z axis to 0. Move them down slightly. Delete the vertices at the bottom.

[image]

You now have a hexagon shaped landscape.